# android studio update flavors vs 3.0

Tags: android, build

After update android studio vs 3.0 my flavors doesn´t work and can´t launch project, this is my configuration on 2.3

```
productFlavors {
       live {
               applicationId "my.package.live"
            }
        }
```

This worked on android studio 2.3

Now on my android studio 3.0, I have this

```
flavorDimensions "live"

   productFlavors {
       live {
             dimension "connections"
            }
    }

connections{
applicationId "my.package.live"
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
dimension "live"
}
```

Tthis give this error

> Error:(30, 0) Could not find method connections() for arguments
>   [build_6pj90fh7u0cgtgk338sofwha$_run_closure1$_closure6@7d2e4344] on
>   object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension. Open
>   File

Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: try this link may help you https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: UltimateDevil if you look at my question I already follow that steps, and it´s not working at all, just check please.